Popular idiomatic phrase to convey "false pride"?
Being from India, "false pride" is one of my favorite words, as it encapsulates a lot of our culture IMHO.
I couldn't think of any idiom/proverb describing the same sentiments.
I am trying to express the feeling

Middle class Indian is living in false pride/show-off/pretentious life-style.

Could somebody please recommend me a phrase/proverb to convey these feeling?
My research yielded Full of hot air/Paper tiger, and I am not satisfied with them.

This might be a better fit for English language and usage: there are similar questions like this, this, this, this + more

@StuartF I did not realize that there was an epidemic. :)

I don't know what living in false pride/show-off/pretentious life-style is supposed to mean. Does the person actually have the power / knowledge / status he claims (but it's not something he should be proud of)? If he doesn't have it, is he trying to gain status by deliberately lying, or is he delusional?

At least in American English, there is the phrase keeping up with the Joneses, which means trying to keep your lifestyle up to the same level as your neighbors (with "Jones" just being a generic and common last name).

self-important ... vain

Aside: the UK media show Goodness Gracious Me thoroughly exploited the Indian middle-class rivalry described.

@WeatherVane out of curiosity, are American tv shows like friends/seinfeld/breaking-bad popular in UK?

@Max the first two are shown on UK television. Never heard of breaking-bad.

@WeatherVane Thanks for your response. I am curious how the humor of those shows is received critically in UK, given the famous (in my humble opinion) sense of humour of British.

It really depends on the sort of context you want to use the phrase. Is it in a polite or semi-polite context? In that case you could use idioms like 'one-upmanship' or 'keeping up with the Joneses' mentioned by @WeatherVane and @CanadianYankee. ('Keeping up with the Joneses' is a common idiom in British English too).

Middle class people are involved in a constant game of one-upmanship with their neighbours.


Middle class people are constantly trying to keep up with the Joneses.

Another similar idiom is 'all for show'. Pretending to be impressive, but lacking substance in reality.

That man is all for show. He drives an expensive car, but lives in a tent.

More crudely, there are many phrases that aren't so suitable for polite conversation that describe the same phenomenon. Some are found in regional dialects, such as 'they're all fur coat and no drawers' in Scotland. (Literally this means 'wearing a fur coat on the outside, but being too poor to afford underwear underneath'.) Or 'they're all mouth and no trousers', which is common in the rest of Britain. Both suggest that someone is 'all for show, but hiding a lack of genuine substance or wealth' in a way that could be considered offensive or at best impolite.

I offer

one-upmanship
a situation in which someone does or says something in order to prove that they are better than someone else
The researchers discovered that moving among certain social groups involves participating in constant one-upmanship.

From Cambridge Dictionary, and Merriam-Webster has

one-upmanship
the art or practice of outdoing or keeping one jump ahead of a friend or competitor
engaged in a round of verbal one-upmanship

